# how to group index db in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a problem when I create an index in models file, I need grouping index like this (dt_cot, dt_cri) and another group index (id_inv) in a table, my code is below:

```
class ModelTable(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     
     class Meta:
           indexes01 = [models.Index(fields=['dt_cot', 'dt_cri'])]
           indexes02 = [models.Index(fields=['id_inv'])]
```

the problem is when I do 'makemigrations', the error display: "TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): indexes01, indexes02".

please how to grouping indexes.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`indexes`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#indexes) is a *list* of `Index` objects, so:

```
class ModelTable(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     
     class Meta:
           indexes = [
               models.Index(fields=['dt_cot', 'dt_cri']),
               models.Index(fields=['id_inv'])
           ]
```

for an index on a *single* field however, you can use the [**`db_index=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index), for example:

```
class ModelTable(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     id_inv = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True)
     
     class Meta:
           indexes = [
               models.Index(fields=['dt_cot', 'dt_cri'])
           ]
```